# why is yum's tab completion slow while apt-get's tab completion is fast?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, apt, yum, autocomplete

Why is yum's tab completion slow while apt-get's tab completion is fast? I'm not sure but I believe that this may have to do with the fact that for autocomplete yum looks over the internet and apt-get has a file locally stored to look from. If this is the case then is there any particular reason why yum doesn't do the same i.e store a local copy to search from?

Comment: Interesting question. I think it is because dnf is checking metadata on every run, while apt never does this unless specifically requested with `apt update`. But I got lost trying to track down in the python code...